# How to override the terminal title bar preferences in Vim

Tags: macos, terminal

I have only the `Working directory or document` and `Active process name` preferences checked for Terminal window titles. Then in VIM I use a custom `titlestring`. However, the title bar is displayed as "<directory `vim` was executed in> — <custom `titlestring`> — vim". What I would like to do is remove the directory part as well as the trailing vim part, but if I uncheck those options in the Terminal preferences, then it applies to every Terminal window, and the result is all non-Vim terminal windows just display "Terminal" in the title bar.

Is there a way to make it so that Vim can override the default Terminal title bar preferences and have the title bar only display `titlestring`?

Comment: Can we know what terminal emulator it is and what is your `titlestring`? I believe it simply wraps the title string in `<directory>` and `- <command>`.

Comment: @Quasímodo What is the relevance of the specific type of terminal emulator? I'm using macOS's 'Terminal' application, is that not specific enough? My `titlestring` is equal to `%f`. Also it doesn't simply do that. What is displayed in the title bar is dependent on your terminal window preferences, and your Vim `title` and `titlestring` settings; with other Vim settings potentially affecting it as well, but from those I have seen, none enabling you to discard the strings injected into the titlebar by the Terminal application itself.